# Shift and Rotate operations not working on 8086 trainer kit, why?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I've been doing some coding on **8086 trainer kit.** Due to some reason the `SHR,SHL,SAL,SAR,ROL,ROR` operations are not working on it. if i write a statement like

```
MOV AX,16
SHR AX,2
```

it will be stuck at the line `SHR AX,2` like if there was some syntax error. similar is the case with other shift & rotate operations.

the only way i was able to make it work was using the **CL** register.

when I changed the code to

```
MOV AX,16
MOV CL,2
SHR AX,CL
```

it executed , but the value at `AX` was supposed to be `4` instead it was `5`.

also for this code

```
  MOV AX,32
  MOV CL,2
  SHR AX,CL
```

The value in `AX` was `12` but it was supposed to be `8`.

what is happening here? Am I doing anything wrong?

**NOTE**: please dont tell me to use DIV & MUL instead of shift operation, cause it become very complex when used in large programs.

Comment: The 8086 didn't have shifts by immediates > 1. The shift amount must be the immediate 1, or `cl`.

Comment: And regarding your results: 32h >> 2 = 12, and 16h >> 2 = 5. So it seems like the assembler you're using defaults to interpreting immediates in base 16.

Comment: @Michael: I wonder if it's DEBUG.EXE?  I thought all other x86 assemblers defaulted to decimal.  But that wouldn't explain rejecting 186 and 286 instructions by default, I don't think.  Maybe emu8086 has a setting for that, or maybe it does default that way and it had never come up in an SO question before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when an operation like `MOV AX,16` is done the value is represented internally as `0000 0000 0001 0110`. so the content of `AX` register is now `0000 0000 0001 0110`.

so when a shift operation `SHR AX,CL` is done, where `CL` is 2 then value in `AX` will become `0000 0000 0000 0101` which is `5`.

That's why

`MOV AX,16
 MOV CL,2
 SHR AX,CL`

has given `5` after the shift operation.

Comment: thanks, @Peter Cordes for the help in making a conclusion

Answer (score 1):

For the 2nd part of your question, once you got it to assemble and got `16 >> 2 = 5` when you were expecting `4`:

That is because **your assembler is treating all numbers as HEX** (base 16).

If you have `16` hex, that's binary `0001 0110`, well you shift 2 times will got
`0000 0101` and that is 5,
 `0 = 8`, `1= 4`, `0=2`, `1=1`

`0x16 >> 2 = 5`

so you need specify 16 base decimal
or work with hexadecimal base

0x16 = 22.  If you want decimal 16, that's `10` in hex.

Comment: Im talking about the number of the AX, not of the shift, in CL is where you will put the number of shift, if is greater than 1, thats right, but why the output of 16 shr 2 is 5 and not 4 is because the base of the number, result is right, logic is not, im talking about diferent thing.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: this is only answering the 2nd half of the question, about 4 vs. 5, but it is actually correct.  I edited it to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> it will be stuck at the line `SHR AX,2` like if there was some syntax error. similar is the case with other shift & rotate operations.

As listed in NASM's instruction reference, SHR with an immediate shift count operand is an 186+ instruction. As you seem to be using emu8086, it isn't supported by your assembler and target machine.

Refer to https://ulukai.org/ecm/insref.htm#insSHL

8086 only has machine-code opcodes for shifts by `cl` and shifts by an implicit `1`.  Writing `shr ax,1` assembles to an instruction with no immediate, just the opcode for shifting by an implicit count of `1`.

Other counts aren't supported because there's no available encoding until 186.

You can shift by 2 using `shr` twice, or for larger counts by `mov cl, 7` / `shr ax, cl`.  (For a large count like 8, it may be faster to `mov al, ah` / `mov ah,0` on a real 8086 where each count of a shift takes an extra cycle.)